# WebView showing a blank page (not loading I think)

Tags: flutter, dart, android-webview

So I am exploring flutter while working on a project. I want to make a simple news list application with dynamic list and a webview to open the full article. However, the WebViewScaffold is showing a blank page.

Tried Flutter Inspector to try and find the error but couldn't get it. Tried changing classes and states.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'makeCard.dart';
import 'webService.dart';
import 'constants.dart';
import 'NewsArticle.dart';
import 'package:flutter_webview_plugin/flutter_webview_plugin.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:http/http.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'newsDetail.dart';


void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(primaryColor: Color.fromRGBO(58, 66, 86, 1.0)),
      home: NewsList(),
    );
  }
}

class NewsListState extends State<NewsList> {
  List<NewsArticle> _newsArticles = List<NewsArticle>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _populateNewsArticles();
  }

  void _populateNewsArticles() {
    Webservice().load(NewsArticle.all).then((newsArticles) => {
          setState(() => {_newsArticles = newsArticles})
        });
  }

  ListTile _buildItemsForListView(BuildContext context, int index) {
    return ListTile(
      title: _newsArticles[index].urlToImage == null
          ? Image.asset(Constants.NEWS_PLACEHOLDER_IMAGE_ASSET_URL)
          : Image.network(_newsArticles[index].urlToImage),
      subtitle:
          Text(_newsArticles[index].title, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18)),
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 10.0),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('News'),
        ),
        body: new Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 2.0, right: 2.0),
          child: new Card(
            child: new ListView.separated(
              separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Divider(
                    height: 10.0,
                  ),
              itemCount: _newsArticles.length,
              itemBuilder: _buildItemsForListView,
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}

class NewsList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  createState() => NewsListState();
}
class Constants {

  static final String HEADLINE_NEWS_URL = 'https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&apiKey=3f85510c67ef4757b65bc2cd96a9eaf9';
  static final String NEWS_PLACEHOLDER_IMAGE_ASSET_URL = 'assets/placeholder.png';

}
class Resource<T> {
  final String url;

  T Function(Response response) parse;

  Resource({this.url, this.parse});
}

class Webservice {
  Future<T> load<T>(Resource<T> resource) async {
    final response = await http.get(resource.url);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return resource.parse(response);
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load data!');
    }
  }
}
class DetailPage extends StatefulWidget {
  DetailPage(this.url);

  final String url;

  @override
  createState() => DetailPageState(this.url);
}

  class DetailPageState extends State<DetailPage> {
  var _url;
  DetailPageState(this._url);



  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(
          "Full Article",
        ),
      ),
      body: new Container(
        child: new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            MaterialApp(
              routes: {
                "/": (_) => new WebviewScaffold(
                  url: _url,
                  appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text("")),
                  hidden:true,
                )
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      );
  }
}
class NewsArticle {

  final String url;
  final String title;
  final String descrption;
  final String urlToImage;
  final String publishedAt;
  final String content;


  NewsArticle({this.url,this.title, this.descrption, this.urlToImage,this.publishedAt,this.content
  });

  factory NewsArticle.fromJson(Map<String,dynamic> json) {
    return NewsArticle(
        title: json['title'],
        descrption: json['description'],
        urlToImage: json['urlToImage'] ?? Constants.NEWS_PLACEHOLDER_IMAGE_ASSET_URL,
        url: json['url'],
        publishedAt: json['publishedAt'],
        content: json['content']
    );
  }
  static Resource<List<NewsArticle>> get all => Resource(
      url: Constants.HEADLINE_NEWS_URL,
      parse: (response) {
        final result = json.decode(response.body);
        Iterable list = result['articles'];
        return list.map((model) => NewsArticle.fromJson(model)).toList();
      }
  );
}
class NewsListState extends State<NewsList> {
  List<NewsArticle> _newsArticles = List<NewsArticle>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _populateNewsArticles();
  }

  void _populateNewsArticles() {
    Webservice().load(NewsArticle.all).then((newsArticles) => {
          setState(() => {_newsArticles = newsArticles})
        });
  }

  ListTile _buildItemsForListView(BuildContext context, int index) {
    return ListTile(
      title: _newsArticles[index].urlToImage == null
          ? Image.asset(Constants.NEWS_PLACEHOLDER_IMAGE_ASSET_URL)
          : Image.network(_newsArticles[index].urlToImage),
      subtitle:
          Text(_newsArticles[index].title, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18)),
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 10.0),
      onTap: () {
        var url = _newsArticles[index].url;
        Navigator.push(context,
            new MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => new DetailPage(url),
        ));
      },
    );
  }

  Card makeCard(BuildContext context, int index) {
    return Card(
      elevation: 8.0,
      margin: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 6.0),
      child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Color.fromRGBO(64, 75, 96, .9)),
          child: _buildItemsForListView(context, index)
      ),
    );
  }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(58, 66, 86, 1.0),
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0.1,
        backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(58, 66, 86, 1.0),
        title: Text('News'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.list),
            onPressed: () {},
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: _newsArticles.length,
          itemBuilder: makeCard,
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: Container(
        height: 55.0,
        child: BottomAppBar(
          color: Color.fromRGBO(58, 66, 86, 1.0),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: <Widget>[
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.home, color: Colors.white),
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.blur_on, color: Colors.white),
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.hotel, color: Colors.white),
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.account_box, color: Colors.white),
                onPressed: () {},
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class NewsList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  createState() => NewsListState();
}


The console log for the error -

D/ViewRootImpl@e393259[MainActivity]( 3890): ViewPostIme pointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@e393259[MainActivity]( 3890): ViewPostIme pointer 1
I/flutter ( 3890): Another exception was thrown: BoxConstraints forces an infinite height.
I/flutter ( 3890): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderStack#59935 relayoutBoundary=up8 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 3890): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: _RenderTheatre#f69a8 relayoutBoundary=up7 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 3890): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#677d7 relayoutBoundary=up6 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 3890): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderAbsorbPointer#b985b relayoutBoundary=up5 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 3890): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPointerListener#86c3b relayoutBoundary=up4 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 3890): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderCustomPaint#b0c68 relayoutBoundary=up3 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 3890): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#c9989 relayoutBoundary=up2 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 3890): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFlex#050d5 relayoutBoundary=up1 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 3890): Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The method '<=' was called on null.
```

Answer (score 3):

Add this line to AndroidManifest.xml then Restart your application.

**step 1:**
Find `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

**File path:** `Android >> app >> main >> AndroidManifest.xml`

**step 2:**
Add this line before `application` tag

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

**step 3:**
Restart your application.

I hope this answer help you :)

Comment: do you know if iOS needs something similar?

Comment: I don't think iOS need same thing, this permission only used when you use a release copy of android application. So iOS do not need same thing or anything similar.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible cause of this could be passing a widget to WebviewScaffold.bottomNavigationBar. I don't know why this happens, but when I removed the widget passed to this and passed the widget to WebviewScaffold.persistentFooterButtons instead, the page was rendered, and my footer widget was rendered. It seems widget passed to bottomNavigationBar  is rendered atop the WebView.